# img tags disappearing completely after sync

Tags: macos, evernote

I have a note uploaded via API (see `bugdemo.xml`). The note uploads without error, syncs to the desktop app (MacOS) and displays properly. When I export the note using the desktop app, it has the expected content - see `bugdemo.before.enex`.

After making any change in the note (in this case adding the word "potato" to third line) in the desktop app and performing sync, the img tags disappear completely - see `bugdemo.after.enex`

So either there's a bug in the desktop app, or there's a problem with the note content. However, I have double checked and it seems to me that the note does not violate any of the ENML rules.

Can anyone help?

All mentioned files can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tvw5w2nzfi2dpiw/AACmzPAcFr17ZHdZ_b26qkfLa?dl=0

*P.S. Editing the note in the web app does not cause the images to disappear, which would only support the claim that there's a bug in the desktop app.*

*P.P.S. I contacted Evernote Support but no luck there - they pointed me here, saying the support is only for end users, not developers :(*

Comment: This could be a Mac client bug. Reported the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Kentaro